# Devise Invitable display invited users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I'm using the [devise_invitable gem](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) along with `Devise` but I can't figure out how to show a list of all invited users. **I want to list all invited users with their status of accepted/pending**.

I have already made a custom Invitations controller (as per the official documentation) that inherits from Devise's controller in which I have a super statement so that it doesn't change functionality but rather adds some below the super. I've scoured issues related to this one and found very few but they use a completely different and unrelated approach. Any input is appreciated~

For example, trying to access @users from invitations/new view throws an `undefined method 'each'`.

Comment: I think you can just fetch users by the column value of **invitation_token** , if it is not `nil` then the user is invited and same way if **invitation_accepted_at** is `nil` then status is pending, otherwise accepted.

Comment: My doubt was how can I access users in my invitations controller?

Comment: To expand on this, stating `@users = User.all` in my invitations controller and looping through them in my `invitations/new` with `<% @users.each do |user| %> <%= @users.email %> <% end %>` throws an `'undefined method 'each' for NilClass` as if I hadn't assigned the variable in my controller~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `invitations_controller` you can simply add this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

You don't need to inherit from Devise, just from the `ApplicationController`. You will be able to access the `@users` variable, now if you want to separate the results into two separate arrays then:

```
def index
  @pending_users = User.where(invitation_accepted_at: nil)
  @accepted_users = User.where.not(invitation_accepted_at: nil)
end
```

And your view you can access the `@pending_users` as well as `@accepted_users`

Comment: Won't that last block of code group standard registered users (ones that registered without an invitation) into the "pending" group? You should check for `invitation_created_at` too.